# Is there a limit to the number of jobs that I can queue using "at"?

Tags: at

I'm using `at` to schedule email reminders. The number of jobs that I could queue could be several thousands at a time. Is this possible or do I have to find another solution?

Comment: Probably possible. If it's a good solution depends on the jobs themselves. If some jobs need to run after others, then schedule them together as one job. Are you expecting some jobs to run at the same time and is that ok? Are the jobs "heavy" (running for long and/or using lots of RAM or CPU)? If so, then `batch` or some third party queuing system may be a better fit.

Comment: A job is just one curl command that would trigger an email to be sent from some php script. I do intend to batch some of the jobs but even then the number would still be in the thousand range.

Comment: [The source](https://searchcode.com/file/21119159/at-3.1.13/at.c), l.209 suggests there may be a limit of 2^20 queued jobs, so this is probably not the limit you will run into.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Thanks, that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: IIRC, there is a configuration file /etc/cron.d/queuedefs which specifies the maximum the number of jobs that will be started in any one minute by cron, at and batch. I can see references in AIX, Solaris, HP-UX, SuSe, but not for Linux.

Comment: I might be wary of starting 1000+ jobs at once. `at` only takes time specifiers to hh:mm accuracy. You might consider putting something like `sleep $(( RANDOM % 60))` at the start of each job to break up the demand, or write your commands to an intermediate file and use `at` to schedule your own throttled despatcher.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Would sending a 1000+ Http request at the same time using curl pose a problem if I relied on at? If so, are there any alternatives?

Comment: I don't claim any special knowledge, just a tendency not to risk traumatising a system. If every job starts with an at, a pdf script, a curl, and a TCP connect, then doing all that thousands of times  on the same clock tick needs at least to be assessed for your hardware and connectivity. The alternative to massive parallelism is serialisation: put identical messages in one email with many bcc's; put a queue of commands in a file and have that despatched at intervals. It depends if you have peaks and troughs, and if your system can even cope with the average rate.

Answer (score 0):

The limit is 1 048 576 jobs in the queue. Over that count, this will start over at 1 and may overwrite queued job.

As mentionned by [Ulrich Schwarz](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/3929/ulrich-schwarz), you can check his [source](https://searchcode.com/file/21119159/at-3.1.13/at.c).

I tested it on my computer to confirm that with this :

```
for i in `seq 1 1048576`; do echo "echo 1" | at 16:00; done
```